# Из сервисов Google Workspace пропал Gmail

Tags: email, gmail

Ситуация такая приобрел подписку Business Standard в Google Workspace(сделал это через британскую сим карту). Подключил домен, все как в инструкции. По началу Gmail был доступен. Через некоторое количество времени он пропал(его нету нигде, он 100 процентов не выключен в настройках). В чем может быть причина? Как его вернуть ?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.